# JSON.Net parse Facebook Graph JSON for all messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api, json.net

Using JSON.Net (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) and the following code:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


@{

    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me&fields=id%2Cname%2Cposts.limit(3)&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1";
    var syncClient = new WebClient();
    var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

    JObject facebook = JObject.Parse(content);

    //To-Do: Get all messages as list<string> using LINQ for JSON
    // Ex:  IList<string> allDrives = o["Drives"].Select(t => (string)t).ToList();




}
```

How would I get a List<> of all messages given the following JSON format (http://www.codeshare.io/EvIdN).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 that this code is working and cool, i've being looking for something like that in w while, thank you so much, the answer is also working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting all messages as strings (no error checking):

```
var arr = ((JArray) obj["posts"]["data"]).Select(e => (string) ((JValue) e["message"]).Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!  I will be sure to build in the error checking.

Comment: great way to querry the data